# Google Chrome Crashes on Monterey

Tags: google-chrome, crash, monterey, apple-silicon

Google Chrome is crashing on Monterey whenever I click on certain dropdown elements (i.e. select).
I've tried resetting everything: uninstalling Chrome, deleting all files in user and /Application Support directories etc, reinstalling Chrome without any extensions added and without sync on.
The error is happening with Chrome 102 and it also happened with version 101.
When I downgrade to version 99 all works well.

Just to give an example of where it happens, I just have to open amazon.com, look for a random product and then click on any of the options in the "Sort By" dropdown in the top-right of the page. The browser then crashes instantly.

This is just an example, it can also happen on other websites with similar control elements.

I've tried getting debug logs and have a massive file without anything that I can make any sense of.
In the terminal, I get to see the following error:

```
[0601/122211.510914:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[1]    22620 abort      /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --v=1
```

Some of files that I have deleted (list is not complete)

```
rm -r /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/Google\ Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.google.Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.google.Chrome.savedState/
rm ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Actives/com.google.Chrome
rm ~/Library/Google/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Speech/Speakable\ Items/Application\ Speakable\ Items/Google\ Chrome/
```

My system:

Apple macbook M1 Pro

macOS Monterey 12.4

Chrome 102.0.5005.61

Is there anything else that could be tried?

Comment: You should file a Bug Report with Google here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315

Comment: Did you ever find out what is the problem? I have the same thing but my mac is not an M1 one.

Comment: @distante I was never able to determine the problem. I submitted a bug report to Google but never received a response. I previously blocked all updates and kept using Chrome 99.0. Recently, I tried version 108, and the issue seems to have been resolved.